# Loop always returns last value of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Currently in TinyMCE 4 I'm trying to add emoticons as buttons in my toolbar.

The code below works fine, I can see all buttons in the toolbar:

```
var array = ['applause', 'bumping', 'cool', 'cry', 'grin', 'happy', 'laughing', 'notalking', 'sad', 'wink'];

    for (var i in array) {

        editor.addButton(array[i], {
            title: '',
            icon: true,
            image: 'img/smileys/'+ array[i] +'.gif',
            onclick: function() {
                editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="img/smileys/'+ array[i] +'.gif">');
            }
        });

    }
```

However, the `array[i]` in the `editor.execCommand` line, always return its value as `wink` (last value of the array). Meanwhile, the other two instances of `array[i]` in the code works just fine.

Comment: that is called function scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close over `i`

```
for (var i in array) {
  new function(){
    var iCopy = i;
    editor.addButton(array[iCopy ], {
        title: '',
        icon: true,
        image: 'img/smileys/'+ array[iCopy ] +'.gif',
        onclick: function() {
            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="img/smileys/'+ array[iCopy ] +'.gif">');
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the object constructor? Seems like needless overhead.

Comment: @cookiemonster - As opposed to (function(){ })()? I am not sure how much overhead it creates in relation to using an IIFE, however I am fairly certain that it is negligible. This way reads clearer to me.

Comment: Fair enough. Just didn't know why you chose that approach.